# How to declare events on a class library (DLL) and catch them on a form?

Tags: vb.net

I need to set events on a class library and catch them in an form.

For example, I run a sub in the [DLL file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library), and I need to "receive" the event that the sub in the class is running.

The DLL file is created by me in Visual Basic, but how do I raise events on it to be catched in the form?

Please provide an example.

Comment: What type of class library? Managed or unamanged? One you created?
The sub raises an event and you need to catch it?
Please provide more information.

Comment: The dll is creted by me in vb, but i don't know how raise events on it to be catched in the form.

Comment: You handle events, you dont catch them :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Code in the dll**

```
 Public Event MySpecialEvent ()

 Private Sub Test 
   RaiseEvent MySpecialEvent
 End Sub
```

**Code in the form**

```
 Private _MyDll as MyDLL

 Public Sub Main
   _MyDLL = New MyDLL
   AddHandler _MyDLL.MySpecialEvent, AddressOf MySpecialEventHandler
 End Sub

 Private Sub MySpecialEventHandler
   'Put your code here to act upon the handled event
 End Sub
```

You'll also need to remove the event handler at some point in the form's life with

```
RemoveHandler _MyDLL.MySpecialEvent, AddressOf MySpecialEventHandler
```

Comment: You can also include a parameter in the event if you need to pass data to the listening code

Public Event MySpecialEvent(S as String)

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about a 'native' unmanaged DLL there is not a direct way to achieve this.
You must declare a method signature that should be used for this event.
Then you must need to provide a way to put a pointer to a method matching this signature into the DLL (provide a callback method). From the DLL you then can call this method when necessary (instead of triggering the event).